# How do you sort lines that are numbered? Java

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to sort in lines that are number (ex. 1.etc..., 2.etc..., 3.etc...). I have tried SortedSet TreeSet.

`SortedSet<String> s = new TreeSet<String>();`

taking the input like so

`for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()){
        s.add(line);
    }`

Everytime I try to output I don't get the right info, I print like this

`for (String text : s){
    w.println(text);
        }`

Comment: The first word of each string is a number?

Comment: @Bohemian Yes can be 2 digit number too

Comment: split the string and get the number. use HashMap for this. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Do you want to sort the strings numerically (by number) or do you want to ignore the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

```
String no = line.subString(0, line.indexOf("."));
Integer intNo = Integer.valueOf(no);
TreeMap<Integer, String> myMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
myMap.put(intNo, line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide a suitable Comparator:

```
Set<String> s = new TreeSet<String>(Comparator.comparing(s -> 
    Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("\\D.*", ""))));
```

The Comparator lambda first removes all characters from the first non-digit onwards, then parses the result as a number, handing that to the helper method to compare.

If you don't provide a Comparator, natural ordering is used, which for Strings is lexigraphical (alphabetic) order is used in which `"100"` is "less than" `"11"`, which is "less than" `"2"`.

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: Wouldn't `new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("\\D.*", ""))))` be easier, so you don't have to repeat the parsing code?

Answer (score 0):

You can program to the `Set` interface (no need to specify `SortedSet`), and the way you ensure that it sorts in the desired way is to provide a `Comparator<String>`; one way to do that, is to compile a `Pattern` and match your input with a *regular expression* like

```
Set<String> s = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<String>() {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.(.+)");

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Matcher m1 = p.matcher(o1);
        Matcher m2 = p.matcher(o2);
        if (m1.matches() && m2.matches()) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(1));
            int b = Integer.parseInt(m2.group(1));
            int r = Integer.compare(a, b);
            if (r != 0) {
                return r;
            }
            return m1.group(2).compareTo(m2.group(2));
        }
        return 0;
    }
});
```

And while your current method will work, the *idiomatic* way to read your lines would be something like

```
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    s.add(line);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't pattern `"^\\d+"` be better? More lenient on what terminates line number, and faster since it doesn't have to scan rest of line text.

Comment: Why are you assuming that duplicate line numbers should be sorted lexicographically by remaining text, rather than just retain original ordering? --- As for my previous comment, faster is likely a bad reason, since solution should pre-parse line numbers if performance was truly an issue.